# java rmi call failure across different jvm versions

Tags: java, jvm, rmi

I have existing rmi server running with jvm 1.5 and client running in jvm 1.6 communicating with no issues.

However, when i run (server under JVM 1.7/ client jvm1.7) OR (server under JVM 1.7/ client jvm 1.6)getting following error -

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is:
java.io.EOFException  
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is:
java.io.EOFException
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at com.tmobile.kiosk.simulator.Kiosk.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.tmobile.kiosk.simulator.Kiosk.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
```

With (Server jvm 1.5/ client jvm 1.7) getting following error -

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.yyy.zzzserver.ZZZServerFactoryImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
```

Is this happening due to RMI changes across Java versions?
Can i run rmi Server in JVM 1.7 without any code changes so that existing clients (jvm 1.5 etc) can connect to it.
We are not rebuilding the jar file which was built probably using java 1.4 or 1.5.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem was some old jar versions being part of classpath.